# Swift crashes when update published value inside a thread synchronously on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, combine

I have several steps need to be processed synchronously. And the value resulted from the process are consumed by the view. It's working on iOS 14, but **it's crashing on iOS 13**. I use a Combine to publish an event to update the value stored inside the view model.

This is the PublisherManager:

```
final class PublisherManager {
    static let shared = PublisherManager()
    private var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    func mainPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<MainInput, Never> {
        mainSubject
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    let mainSubject = PassthroughSubject<MainInput, Never>()

    enum MainInput {
        case updateValue()
    }
}
```

This is the view model:

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var status: Status = .checking

    init() {
        setObserver()
        start()
    }

    private func setObserver() {
        PublisherManager.shared.mainPublisher()
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { [weak self] action in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                switch action {
                case .updateValue:
                    self.updateValue()
                }
            }.store(in: &cancellable)
    }

    func start() {
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        let dispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

        dispatchGroup.enter()
        dispatchQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {
            dispatchSemaphore.wait()
            self.getValues { //--> A process to call API
                PublisherManager.shared.pushNotificationTroubleshooterSubject.send(.updateValue())
                dispatchSemaphore.signal()
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
        
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            // Notify
        }
    }
    
    private func updateValue() {
        status = .active
    }
}
```

When I run it, I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the AppDelegate but it doesn't print any error at all on the debugger. If I comment the `status = .active` code, it doesn't crash.

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: `DispatchGroup` and `DispatchSemaphore` to force an asynchronous task to become synchronous is a horrible practice. Especially in a `Combine` context which makes the handling of asynchronous tasks so pretty convenient . `DispatchGroup` is the wrong API anyway. It's been designed to control the timing in a **group** of (multiple) asynchronous tasks in a loop.

Comment: @vadian but then how to tackle it? I mean, I tried using the `dispatchQueue.sync` but it doesn't work otherwise

Comment: As I said, Combine provides operators to ***combine*** asynchronous tasks smoothly.

Comment: @vadian Hmm I am afraid I didn't quite catch that, can you please elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you did with `DispatchGroup` and `DispatchSemaphore` is wrong. The concept of combine this is an similar to asynchronous code execution. So instead of using `DispatchGroup` and `DispatchSemaphore` just use chain of publishers with combineLeates and do actions depend on received events

Comment: The answer is unclear, please edit your answer to add some detail, specially some code to describe the workflow. Do keep in mind the question specifies he requires  timing the tasks as to keep from overloading the API call more often than once a second.